# How do I customize button and link labels in Azure B2C login page?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Using Azure AD B2C, I want to change the signup link text that says "Sign up now" to say "Create an account". How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using User flows or Custom Policies (Identity Experience Framework)?

If you are using the user flow, go to [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_B2CAdmin/TenantManagementMenuBlade/userJourneys) and select user flow you like to customize. You will see the languages tab on lower left. Click on it then choose the language, for example English. Next download the JSON file for page level resource.

[image: Page level resource]

Now, download the JSON file:

[image: Page level resource JSON]

Change the value inside the JSON:

```
{
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "createaccount_link",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Sign up now"
    },
```

To:

```
{
      "ElementType": "UxElement",
      "ElementId": null,
      "StringId": "createaccount_link",
      "Override": false,
      "Value": "Create an account"
    },
```

Finally, upload the file back and you should now have updated text for the link.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case any body need to change the text on singing signup page using custom policies, you also can use the Localization customization to add the text that you need for specific language.

Those are the instructions
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-localization

Answer (score 1):

**Few Corrections on the answer shared by @Razi**

1. Download the Json file from **Unified Sign up or sign in page** instead of **Local Account Sign Up Page**.
2. Make Sure to Modify the Override value to **true** so that B2C will able to detect the change, if there is no true value in the Override you will see below error while uploading the file.

[image]

**Few Inputs from my side**

User flows supports 2 options now as per below Screenshot:

[image]

If you have selected **Recommended** Version use the below Json:

```
{
  "ElementType": "UxElement",
  "ElementId": null,
  "StringId": "createaccount_one_link",
  "Override": true,
  "Value": "Create an account"
}
```

For the **Standard** Version **@Razi** already answered above.